# pytest_snapshot snaphot removal

Tags: python, pytest, snapshot-testing

If I have a tests folder structure like this
-tests
--**init**.py
--test_main.py

And my test looks like this:

```
from pytest_snapshot.plugin import Snapshot

def test_my_func(snapshot: Snapshot) -> None:
    output = "test output"
    snapshot.assert_match(output, "testing.txt")
```

When I run `pytest tests` the initial run fails.

Then I run `pytest tests --snapshot-update` and it creates the snapshot.

Now the `pytest tests` run passes.

When I remove the `test_my_func()` function and I run `pytest tests --snapshot-update --allow-snapshot-deletion` the snapshot does NOT get deleted.

The steps above are a minimal reproducable example of what I wanted to test. The `--allow-snapshot-deletion` flag does not work as expected. According to the `pytest_snapshot` documentation, it should remove the unused snapshots...
https://pypi.org/project/pytest-snapshot/

Am I doing something wrong or is the `--allow-snapshot-deletion` flag not working correctly?